# Args and passing args from position[1] (not position 0)

Tags: go

I am reading a command line string from a config file (config.json) :

```
"execmd" : "c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c runscript.cmd"
```

I want to pass this to `exec.Command()` - but this function requires 2 parameters:

```
exec.Comm*emphasized text*and (cmd, args...)
```

Where cmd is the first segment (cmd.exe) and args would then be every space deliminated value thereafter.

1. I am not exactly sure if I need to read the config string, and then manually split it up in an array for each space deliminator? Is there any way of converting a string into args easily?
2. How would it be possible to do something like this, where I can refer args... from an index? (the below code doesn't work, can't refer args this way)

   ```
   exec.Command (arg[0], args[1]...)
   ```

Answer (score 2):

If the values coming it from the config file are in a format executable by shell, you're going to run into a host of problems just splitting on spaces (e.g. quoted arguments containing spaces). If you want to take in a command line that would be executable in a shell, you're going to want to have a shell execute it:

```
exec.Command("cmd.exe", "/c", execmd)
```

There is no way of "converting a string into args" because it varies from shell to shell.

Comment: yes about the quoted arguments that is where the code also went abit heavy if i have to write it myself. But the string in config should represent a complete shell command so i also will use quoted parameters - is there any way i can convert that into args so it can be supported by the Exec.Command ?

Comment: maybe something like this : https://github.com/mattn/go-shellwords or this : https://godoc.org/bitbucket.org/creachadair/shell

Answer (score -1):

I found this thread regarding the issue : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/pNwqLyfl2co

**Edit 1:** ( didnt work )

And saw this one using RegExp - and found out how i can index into the args also :

```
r := regexp.MustCompile("'.+'|\".+\"|\\S+")
s := appConfig.JobExec.ExecProcess
m := r.FindAllString(s, -1)
Exec.Command (m[0],m[1:])
```

This seems to work also with quoted strings !

**Edit 2:**

It didnt work and didnt work on windows, theres an issue with params being passed on when running with cmd. Using sysprocattr.cmdline will make it work :

```
cmdins := exec.Command(cmd)
cmdins.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{}
for _, arg := range args {
    cmdins.SysProcAttr.CmdLine = cmdins.SysProcAttr.CmdLine + arg + " "
}
```

the issue described here :

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17149

Comment: okay - you got any suggestions ? can it be done by regex or should i abort that route ?

Comment: I don't think a regex without lookarounds (which `pkg/regexp` doesn't support) can do it. You'd have to parse the string, or let a shell do the parsing for you.

Comment: seems there is an issue with windows and cmd using Command - instead i got it working with building the cmdline.